# Trying to create MySQL command where it selects one column and searches two other rows

Tags: php, mysql, post

So I am try ing to create a MySQL command to search a table.  What I want it to do is:

My table has 4 columns: `id`, `categories`, `brands`, `names`.

In php/html
on the search page the user selects a category from a dropdown.  This is the category so this is posted as `category` to the search page.  then thy type in a keyword into the text box.  This is posted `keyword` to the search page.

I want to make a MySQL command that selects the category in `categories` posted then searches those selected rows for my posted keyword in the `brands`, and `names` columns

Here is what I have tried:

```
"SELECT brands, names 
   FROM tableName 
  WHERE categories LIKE".$_GET['category']." 
    AND (brands LIKE ".$_GET['keyword']." 
     OR names LIKE ".$_GET['keyword'].");";
```

Comment: A bit off-topic, but your query is vulnerable to SQL injection; meaning any script kiddie can get complete control over your database. You should not use this code for any serious applications.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Thats much easier to read

Comment: Yes I know @AaRdvarkSoup Just the simple Query.  but I would appreciate in input on that as well if you would.  Never know too much about security.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around strings in SQL. Try this:

```
"SELECT brands, names 
   FROM tableName 
  WHERE categories LIKE '".$_GET['category']."' 
    AND (brands LIKE '".$_GET['keyword']."' 
         OR names LIKE '".$_GET['keyword']."');";
```

Unless you are expecting there to be variations e.g. several words with the same beginning, using LIKE doesn't achieve much. If you are expecting this, you need to use wildcards to specify where you expect the variance to be e.g.

```
brands LIKE '".$_GET['keyword']."%' 
// User enters 'Mc', SQL end up as:
brands LIKE 'Mc%'
// Columns matched: 'McDonalds' 'McHenry'
```

More examples [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

If you don't want to allow for this, just use = instead of LIKE.

You also need to sanitise these variables first using a regular expression or similar, as this would currently allow someone to attack your server with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thank you that worked.  I'm using `LIKE`, because im using Ajax, to create the list as they type. But I did switch the `categories` search to `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Take your command, and play with it in your SQL document editor, I think it is something with your

```
(brands LIKE ".$_GET['keyword']." OR names LIKE ".$_GET['keyword'].");"
```

I know in sqlite, you would use an equals sign, instead of LIKE,

```
 (brands='".$_GET['keyword']."' OR names='".$_GET['keyword']."');"
```